# "The RPC server is unavailable" error from SSIS on failed over cluster server

Tags: ssis, windows-server-2008, rpc, cluster-computing, dcom

During a fail over cluster server on the primary, the secondary server gave this error message:

> Executed as user: LIVE\super_3. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.1600.1 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started:  7:39:10 AM  Could not load package "\File System\Package1" because of error 0xC00160AD.  Description: Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "Cluster2" failed with the following error: "The RPC server is unavailable.  ".    This error occurs when the computer host name does not exist, or cannot be reached.  Source:   Started:  7:39:10 AM  Finished: 7:39:31 AM  Elapsed:  21.029 seconds.  The package could not be loaded.  The step failed.

This error still happen even the firewall had been disabled, and the Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Service in Control Panel's Services have been set to startup automatically and was running.

The Scheduled Job is running on SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

The package is reading a text file into a table.

Comment: Cluster "stuff" is beyond me but was the package running during the failover? I know SSIS is *NOT* [cluster-aware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345193.aspx) so could that explain the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration services is not cluster aware as mentioned in the comment. A failover like you explained is not supported and will not work.

It is recommended to install Integration Services as standalone services on each node in the cluster.

**MSDN says:**

Although the Integration Services service is not a clustered service, you can manually configure the service to operate as a cluster resource after you install Integration Services separately on each node of the cluster. For those customers who conclude that the advantages of this configuration outweigh the disadvantages, this topic contains instructions for configuring the service as a cluster resource.

However, if high availability is your goal in establishing a clustered hardware environment, you can achieve this goal without configuring the Integration Services service as a cluster resource. To manage your packages on any node in the cluster from any other node in the cluster, modify the configuration file for the Integration Services service on each node in the cluster. **You modify each of these configuration files to point to all available instances of SQL Server on which packages are stored.** This solution provides the high availability that most customers need, without the potential problems encountered when the Integration Services service is configured as a cluster resource.

See more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345193.aspx